# Extracting data from html content in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to extract data in between `<div id="navigation"></div>` tags using regular expression from html content(string). Any help is appreciated.

`$html = load($url);

```
preg_match_all ("/<div>(.+?)<\/div>/is",
            $html, &$matches);



$matches = $matches[1];
$list = array();

foreach($matches as $var)
{  
    print("<br>");  
    print($var."<br>");
}`
```

Here I want to retrieve data from a specific div tag.

Comment: Do NOT use regexes on HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068. And... what have you tried so far? We're not going to write something from scratch for you, you have to prove you've at least TRIED to do something first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to to it is by using jquery or you can try this html php phraser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

Try this code

```
<div id='navigation'>
   <p >
       Navigation div contents
  </p>
</div>
```

// Javascript

```
var test= $('#navigation').clone();
alert(test.text());
```

Comment: Hi @Naveen Kumar - Thanks for reply.Here where are you passing url? Could you please explain me?

Comment: What URL are you taking about?

Comment: I mean the content of a external web page from where I'm trying to retrieve some section of data.

Answer (score 0):

As stated: [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068)

```
$url = "http://yo.ur/url/goes/here";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$element = $dom->getElementById('navigation');
echo $element->nodeValue;
```

Also, [PHP load()? Are you kidding me?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.load.php)

Comment: load() is a custom class function which gives me content of webpage.

Comment: Then it should be kind of `$instance->load()`, shouldn't it? And how about `file_get_contents()`?
By the way, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: load() is giving appropriate result i.e html in the form of string. Thats not a problem. I'm sending first form result to a php file where `file_get_contents()` is working fine but when I'm sending second form data to another php file, `file_get_contents()` is not working.